# Add non-adjacent data points to a graph

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

I am trying to generate a line graph using VBA, but the data points are not adjacent on the sheet.
The series are added via a loop and depends on the number of data points entered by the user.

```
 n=5

For p = 2 To n + 1
  ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries


  ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(p).XValues = ActiveSheet.Range("A3" , "C3")
  ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(p).Values = ActiveSheet.Range("A4" , "C4")
Next p
```

Comment: hi,need your help on this!

Comment: try set the data sources as this: activesheet.range("A3" & "," & "C3")

Comment: @Hamed, Solved!!!!, Thank You!

Comment: `"A3" & "," & "C3"` can also be written as `"A3,C3"`